# LINQ - How to group by name from nested array

Tags: c#, list, linq, group-by, grouping

```
_id:"63624b321e78f38a3d6baf3e"
Taxes
[0] TaxName:CGST
    Amount:9.0
[1] TaxName:SGST
    Amount:8.0
_id:"63624b321e78f38a3d6baf3e"
Taxes
[1] TaxName:SGST
    Amount:8.0
```

I need to group by tax name and calculate Total CGST, SGST like below

```
CGST:9.0
SGST:16.0
```

I have tried to get the grouping as below. I have an object like movie summary where I added the `taxes[]` and tried to group by tax name. Please let me know how to do this grouping correctly.

```cs
movieSummary.Add(new DSMovieSummaryReport
                 {
                     MovieId = orderTicket.MovieId,                             
                     Taxes= orderTicket.Taxes,
                 });

var groupByTaxNamesQuery =
    from tax in movieSummary
    group tax by tax.Taxes into newGroup
    orderby newGroup.Key
    select newGroup;
```

Comment: Please provide you data as valid C# code. It makes it much easier to answer then.

Comment: With LINQ i would have done something like
movieSummary.SelectMany(m => m.Taxes).GroupBy(t=>t.TaxeName).Select(g=> new Taxe { TaxeName = g.Key, Amount = g.Sum(t => t.Amount) });

Answer (score 4):

**Concept: Flatten array**

1. Flatten the `Taxes` list to combine all the items from the lists into one list via `.SelectMany()`.
2. Group by `TaxName`.
3. Perform total sum for `Amount`.
4. Lastly, with `.ToList()` to materialize the query execution.

```cs
var groupByTaxNamesQuery =
            from tax in movieSummary.SelectMany(x => x.Taxes)
            group tax by tax.TaxName into newGroup
            orderby newGroup.Key
            select new { TaxName = newGroup.Key, Amount = newGroup.Sum(x => x.Amount) };

var result = groupByTaxNamesQuery.ToList();
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xtsd0f)

---

Thanks to @Svyatoslav Danyliv's suggestion, you can achieve in query expression as below:

```cs
var groupByTaxNamesQuery =
            from ms in movieSummary
            from tax in ms.Taxes
            group tax by tax.TaxName into newGroup
            orderby newGroup.Key
            select new { TaxName = newGroup.Key, Amount = newGroup.Sum(x => x.Amount) };

var result = groupByTaxNamesQuery.ToList();
```

[Demo (Full query expression) @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kmKDZ5)

Comment: Why `SelectMany`? In query syntax it is just `from`, like `from m in movieSummary from tax in m.Taxes`

Comment: Ya, thanks for the correction.  Can be achieved in query expression without mixing with method syntax.

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ i would have done something like :

```
movieSummary
    .SelectMany(m => m.Taxes)
    .GroupBy(t=>t.TaxeName)
    .Select(g=> new Taxe
    {
        TaxeName = g.Key,
        Amount = g.Sum(t => t.Amount)
    });
```